# Find the Area of a rectangle please help

Tags: area

a pool 20 ft by 30 ft is going to have a deck x feet wide added all the way around the pool write an expression in simplified form for the area of the deck. I have tried doing this but have failed please help

Comment: You said you have tried this? Specifically what have you tried?

Comment: I tried (20+x)(30+x) I don't know is it right do I foil next?

Comment: Almost. But when you sketch the deck around the pool, it will be on all four sides. So it will increase the width/length by how much?

Comment: The deck is on all four sides of the pool.  Try drawing a picture.

Comment: I did still does not make sense

Comment: this is algebra 2

Comment: Does not say I'm not supposed to solve just simplify

Comment: @cis draw a rectangle in a rectangle. The outer rectangle will be the deck and the inner will be the pool.

Comment: @yiyi, I think we need to remove the four squares from the four corners if we draw a rectangle in a rectangle.

Comment: @Vikram Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the correct path cris.

The pool is still a rectangle, even with the new deck.  Thus you are almost correct.

Each side will have $x$ feet added to it.

Thus it will be $(20+2x)(30+2x) = 4x^2+100x+600$

Try finding the answer to this:

If there is only 120 Feet of bamboo for the new deck,what is the largest the new area (pool + deck) can be.

Comment: thank you really helped it's 2x because there are 4 side right so 2+2 +4 so basically 2x is acounting for two sides right?

Comment: There are only four side to a rectangle.  Did you draw the rectangle in a rectangle?  It always helps to draw a picture when you want to do mathematical problems.

Comment: I did so is 4x squared + 100x + 600 right what is the point of drawing a rectangle wouldn't it be easier to just foil straight away?

Comment: Cris, it so you can understand what is going on.  Can you see where the deck would be on the outside of the pool.

Comment: yeah so its like a picture frame the frame is the x and the picture is the length and width

Comment: You also need to subtract the area of the pool.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Area of the deck=$20x+20x+30x+30x=100x$

Comment: is this the right answer or the one yiyi gave me?

Comment: this one is right, read your problem and see the diagram above, then use the formula for the area of a rectangle.

Comment: @cris Vikram did a better job of answering the problem than I did. You should accept his answer.

Comment: i'm confused vikram gave me the answer but I only need the expression so wouldn't yours be right yiyi?

Comment: the expression you want (you don't need) is Area of the deck=$2(20*x)+2(30*x)$, simplify this and you will get $100*x$

Comment: added all the way around the pool - been thinking about that phrase and I think that the corners should not be deleted.

Comment: I agree @yiyi , if I hired someone to build a deck around my pool, I would expect the four corners to be included, so I could walk around the pool.

Comment: in that case add $4x^2$, so the area of the deck=$4x^2+100x$

Comment: @Vikram how did you make the picture?

Comment: @yiyi, MS Paint that comes with Windows.